# UWP: NavigationView can't change panel background

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

For testing, I'm using [Xaml-Controls-Gallery](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery) source. But when I try to input

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" Color="Red"/>
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" Color="Red" />
```

nothing changing. Only if I extract XAML code and change **PaneBackground** property in **SplitView**.

***Project info:***

- Target+Min: 1809 (17763)
- Microsoft.UI.Xaml 2.1.190405004.2

Answer (score 1):

I tested `NavigationView`, and the `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" Color="Red"/>` works well, if your Target and Min version is 1809, you have no need to use `NavigationView` with **Microsoft.UI.Xaml** nuget package.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" Color="Red"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" Color="Red" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="nvSample">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Save" Content="Menu Item2" Tag="SamplePage2" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Refresh" Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage3" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Download" Content="Menu Item4" Tag="SamplePage4" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

[image]